# Use CSV or Text file as a data source for SSAS cube

Tags: ssas, olap, olap-cube, rolap

Can we have a CSV or Text file as a data source for SSAS cube.
I deal with lots of data and maintain SSAS cubes (ROLAP) for analyzing the same.
The data(~2 GB) comes in every hour as a formatted text file which I upload to a DB which acts as a data source for the cube. The cube then fetches this data from the DB and processes it. 
I would like to process the cube directly using the text file. This can save a lot time.

Answer (score 1):

I've never really tried this, but I think this is possible if you have the ACE provider.

> To connect to a flat file, you must have the ACE provider installed on your computer.

Source: [Connect to a Flat File (SSAS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471713.aspx)